# getchar() и буфер

Tags: c++, c

Проблема такая: при любом раскладе переменная getchar a возвращает '\n' и выполняет default (goto x), не учитывая остальное. Как можно исправить сие недоразумение?

```
 X:
    int a;
    do
    {
        a = getchar();
    } while (a != '\n' && a != EOF);
    switch (a)
    {
    default:
        goto X;
        break;
    case '0':
        exit(0);
        break;
    case '1':
    printf("%s", "TEST");
    getchar();
    exit(0)
        break;
}
```

Comment: Ну смотрите. Вы написали `while` так, что из него можно выйти только если `a == '\n'` или `a == EOF`.

Comment: HolyBlackCat верно говорит. И используйте обычные циклы. Goto зло и запрещён почти во всех код стайлах.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так, наверное:

```
int pred; // !!!

X:
int a = 0;
do
{
    pred = a; // !!!
    a = getchar();
} while (a != '\n' && a != EOF);
switch (pred) // !!! 
{
default:
    goto X;
    break;
case '0':
    exit(0);
    break;
case '1':
printf("%s", "TEST");
getchar();
exit(0)
    break;
}
```

Мои дополнения помечены *// !!!*. НЕ тестировал !!!